# How to persist redux user login on server (SSR)

Tags: reactjs, redux, server-side-rendering, redux-persist

I have an application that works as expected on the client with user logins, etc.  No problem.

I would like to pre-render some stuff for components which the user can view if they are logged in, however from what I know you can't persist the store on the server.  Makes sense as the store is persisted often in `localstorage` or something on the client.  Plus the `redux-persist` package warns you to conditionally persist only on the client.  I'm doing the following when creating the store.  This will ensure the client exists and persist if it does.  It only persists the user:

```
if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    persistStore(
        store,
        {
            whitelist: ["user"]
        },
        () => {
            store.dispatch(setPersisted());
        }
    ),
}
```

Note that I'm using a `redux-persist 4.9.1` as I had a hell of a time migrating to v5.x.

So, how do we pre-render things that only a logged-in user can see if the store can't be persisted on the server?  Am I going about this totally wrong?